# udevadm doesn't die if parent process experiences an error

Tags: process, pipe, udev, socat

I need to redirect output from `udevadm monitor` to a named pipe. For that end I use the following command:

```
sudo socat -u SYSTEM:"udevadm monitor" PIPE:/tmp/test &
```

It works until a process reading from the pipe is interrupted and `socat` exists with a "Broken pipe" error, which is expected. However, when I list running processes it turns out that `udevadm` is still running.

```
$ ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3539 tty1     00:00:00 bash
 3619 tty2     00:00:00 bash
 3972 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
$ sudo socat -u SYSTEM:"udevadm monitor" PIPE:/tmp/test &
[1] 3973
$ ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3539 tty1     00:00:00 bash
 3619 tty2     00:00:00 bash
 3973 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
 3974 pts/0    00:00:00 socat
 3975 pts/0    00:00:00 socat
 3976 pts/0    00:00:00 udevadm
 3977 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
$ cat /tmp/test
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

^C
$ 2020/06/01 12:36:06 socat[3974] E write(6, 0x1dfbc60, 147): Broken pipe

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo socat -u SYSTEM:"udevadm monitor" PIPE:/tmp/test
$ ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3539 tty1     00:00:00 bash
 3619 tty2     00:00:00 bash
 3976 pts/0    00:00:00 udevadm
 3980 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
$
```

When I replaced `udevadm monitor` with `yes` (to simply feed a stream of data to the pipe), it died along with `socat`.

If I simply interrupt `socat` with `kill` command, `udevadm` perishes neatly.

If I kill parent bash process `socat` and `udevadm` die as well, so I tried wrapping `udevadm` with `sh -c`:

```
sudo socat -u SYSTEM:'sh -c \"udevadm monitor\"' PIPE:/tmp/test &
```

hoping that dying shell would kill `udevadm`, but to no avail.

I am aware, that orphaned process can be adopted by INIT, but it doesn't seem to be the case, because out of all processes only `udevadm` seems to cheat death like this. To sum up my experiments:

1. Process tree bash->sudo->socat->udevadm - kill `socat` - all die
2. Process tree bash->sudo->socat->udevadm - broken pipe - only udevadm lives on
3. Process tree bash->sudo->socat->sh->udevadm - broken pipe - only udevadm lives on
4. Process tree bash->sudo->socat->yes- broken pipe - all die
5. Process tree bash->sudo->socat->udevadm - kill sudo - all die
6. Process tree bash->sudo->socat->udevadm - kill bash - all die

The problem I really want to solve are lingering `udevadm` processes.

My preferred solution would be to `udevadm` die nicely along with other processes. Acceptable solution would be to have persistent pipe, which would not break when reading process dies.

Are there any options or settings I can pass either to `socat` or to `udevadm` to solve my problem?

If `socat` if a wrong tool for my ultimate objective to have `udevadm` output sent to a pipe, I am obviously open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to use a little magic, but you can try inverting the two addresses so you can then add option `nofork` to the system command. You need to swap `-u` to `-U` of course to change direction:

```
socat -U PIPE:/tmp/test SYSTEM:"udevadm monitor",nofork
```

This seems to ignore the closing of the pipe, and you can re-open it again. Don't ask me about the magic.

Comment: This works very nicely, and the pipe it creates a pipe which survives not only reader's death, but even creator's death. I like it, thank you :) But I'll be honest, I wish I knew how the magic works, cargo cult is hardly a sound engineering practice ;)